# define and initilize array from a seperate class

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I have 2 different classes, Employee, PersonnelManager. I am trying to declare and instantiate an array of Employee in PersonnelManager. without using inheritance, just two completely seperate classes

```
public abstract class Employee  {

      private String firstName;
      private String lastName;
      private double wage;

      public Employee() {
         firstName = "";
         lastName = "";
         wage = 0.0;
      }
   }

public  class PersonnelManager {

    public Employee [] EmployeesArray;

    public PersonnelManager() {
        EmployeesArray= {Employee.this()}; // this is not working
    }
```

in the Constructor of PersonnelManager How can I instantiate the array. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize the array like below -

```
public PersonnelManager() {
        EmployeesArray= new EmployeesArray[5]; 
    }
```

or you can pass the size in constructor to make it dynamic-

```
public PersonnelManager(int size) {
            EmployeesArray= new EmployeesArray[size]; 
        }
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class Employee  {

  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private double wage;

  public Employee() {
     firstName = "";
     lastName = "";
     wage = 0.0;
  }
}

public  class PersonnelManager {

public Employee [] EmployeesArray;

public PersonnelManager() {

    EmployeesArray= new Employee[10]; // 10 is the size of an array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to instantiate an empty array of Employees in your PersonnelManager, but you're using the wrong syntax. You can do that with this:

```
EmployeesArray = new EmployeesArray[size];
```

Note that you'll have to supply a size. If you want more flexibility, then you might want to use a List instead of an array:

```
public  class PersonnelManager {

    public List<Employee> employees;

    public PersonnelManager() {
        employees = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```